Anchor build error in solana-dapp
PS D:\coding\solana\voting\anchor> solana --version
solana-cli 2.1.4 (src:024d047e; feat:288566304, client:Agave)
PS D:\coding\solana\voting\anchor> anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.30.1
PS D:\coding\solana\voting\anchor> cargo clean
     Removed 484 files, 56.5MiB total
PS D:\coding\solana\voting\anchor> anchor build
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.86
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.12
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling typenum v1.17.0
   Compiling serde v1.0.204
   Compiling syn v1.0.109
   Compiling thiserror v1.0.63
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.120
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.86
   Compiling semver v1.0.23
   Compiling itoa v1.0.11
   Compiling ryu v1.0.18
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.12
   Compiling unicode-segmentation v1.11.0
   Compiling bs58 v0.5.1
   Compiling autocfg v1.3.0
   Compiling once_cell v1.19.0
   Compiling jobserver v0.1.31
   Compiling hashbrown v0.14.5
   Compiling cc v1.1.6
   Compiling equivalent v1.0.1
   Compiling subtle v2.6.1
   Compiling toml_datetime v0.6.6
   Compiling heck v0.3.3
   Compiling feature-probe v0.1.1
   Compiling winnow v0.5.40
   Compiling zerocopy v0.7.35
   Compiling cfg_aliases v0.2.1
   Compiling rustversion v1.0.17
   Compiling rustc_version v0.4.0
   Compiling borsh v1.5.1
   Compiling bv v0.11.1
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
   Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.4
   Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.4
   Compiling indexmap v2.2.6
   Compiling quote v1.0.36
   Compiling ahash v0.8.11
   Compiling ahash v0.7.8
   Compiling memoffset v0.9.1
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.19
error: couldn't read \\?\D:\Coding\Solana\voting\anchor\target\release\build\typenum-b4aec6864503f063\out/op.rs: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)
  --> C:\Users\Istaprasad Patra\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\typenum-1.17.0\src\lib.rs:72:5
   |
72 |     include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/op.rs"));
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `include` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: could not compile `typenum` (lib) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: couldn't read \\?\D:\Coding\Solana\voting\anchor\target\sbf-solana-solana\release\build\typenum-d2748848315e0718\out/op.rs: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)
  --> src\lib.rs:72:5
   |
72 |     include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/op.rs"));
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `include` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: could not compile `typenum` (lib) due to 1 previous error

I have installed solana-dapp, and after running anchor build I get this error. I have already checked all the paths used in the Cargo.toml and they are right. I have cleaned cache and still getting the same error. I also tried by using cmd as administrator but then also I got this error. How to fix this ?

You're using Windows native rather than WSL2. - sadly, many open source tools including many Rust llibraries assume Unix-style paths. error: couldn't read \\?\D:\Coding\Solana\voting\anchor\target\sbf-solana-solana\release\build\typenum-d2748848315e0718\out/op.rs: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. looks like a Unix/Windows path error. I would install WSL2, and Windows Terminal then install Rust and the Solana CLI inside that.
